# Install4j - Action "Delete files and directories" appends installation directory in front of array values

Tags: java, install4j

I'm writing a project in Install4j that required some special code in the uninstaller to allow partial uninstallation.

I have a `Delete files and directories` action in the uninstallation section with a boolean acting as a flag to fire it or the typical full uninstall action. All of this appears to be working fine.

The issue I am having is the variable I pass to the delete files and directories action (${installer:uninstallDirs}). I have attempted setting this variable to a String Array, or an undefined variable type. With either of those settings, I have attempted to pass it full string paths to the directories, file objects, and relative string paths.

During the action execution, the debug output will show the following.

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.UninstallationScreen [ID 27]: Show screen [INFO]
com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.DeleteFileAction [ID 1495]:
Execute action
       Property directoryFilter: null
       Property fileFilter: null
       Property files: [[suppressed]]
       Property filesRoot: null
       Property backupForRollback: true
       Property recursive: true
       Property rollbackSupported: true
       Property showFileNames: true
       Property showProgress: false
       The file "C:\InstallDir\[C:\InstallDir\Server, C:\InstallDir\Client, C:\InstallDir\Network]" does not exist
       Execute action successful after 14 ms
```

So it appears to be failing because it will put the Install Directory into the value prior to the array, despite the object being passed being an array. I have output the value of the array at a previous section and can confirm that the array is being built correctly.

I suspect this has something to do with the "Make all paths relative when saving the project file" setting, but I don't want to just start changing project settings until it works.

Any suggestions or tests I might try to perform would be greatly appreciated.

[image: See a screenshot of the action setup here]

Comment: Do you maybe have a collection value in the installer variable instead of an array value? The toString() result would indicate that.

Comment: This was actually all that it was. Thank you so much. I had apparently done the conversion correctly for a different variable at a different location in the code, but kept glossing over this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if there is a collection value in the installer variable. As of install4j 7.x, the variable replacement for collection properties only expands installer variables with an array value into separate entries. A collection value will be replaced with its `toString()` value instead of adding all collection items separately.

In install4j 8, collection values will be supported as well.